# jquery form check before submit with select name array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a hard time with this quick validation i want in place...but i think it's not validating properly because of my select name arrays and i'm not sure how to go about this.

How it should work:
- If stat holiday box is checked for that day && if any Lieu hours are selected for that day give alert error and stop form submission.

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bgYj/3/

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

    var lieuhrs = $(".lieutimehours").val();

    $('.lieutimehours').each(function(i, obj) {
        if ($("#statholidaycheck").is(":checked") && lieuhrs > 0) {
            alert("cannot process: " + lieuhrs);
            return false;
        }
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: First - you can't have same id's on page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a more user-friendly approach for your problem:

If `stat` is selected simply *disable* the form input for `lieu hours`.

With this you won't have to check anything before submitting the form and the user can't accidentally select a value in `lieu hours`.

It still needs to be updated to your markup, but the idea is basically:

```
var stat = $('.stat');

stat.change(function() {
    var e = $(this);
    var f = e.parent().find('.lieu');

    if (e.is(':checked')) {
        f.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        f.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/UzhjK/)

Comment: this is a great idea and id rather use this method... just trying to get it to work on my side but having issues... i changed stat check box class="statholidaycheck" but still won't disable the lieu select

Comment: `class="statholidaycheck"` is a good start as you can't have an id multiple times. Your selector should be something like `var f = e.closest('tr').find('.lieutimehours')`.

Comment: @rubberchicken Yep, the selector from above works: http://jsfiddle.net/Zg9uC/ - Glad I could help.

Comment: sorry.. how would i set it to readonly instead of disabled since i still want the zero 0  value to be submitted ?

Comment: I think you can't have a select box to be read only, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing a );...

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
            var lieuhrs = $(".lieutimehours").val();
            $('.lieutimehours').each(function(i, obj) {
                if ($("#statholidaycheck").is(":checked") && lieuhrs > 0) {
                    alert("cannot process: " + lieuhrs);
                    return false;
                }
            }); // missing ); here. <--------------
        });
    });
```

Try it after adding that and you'll find it works for the first checkbox. But select a different checkbox and it will fail. In HTML, you will want to use unique ids to reference an element. What I would do is change your HTML to put a css class on the TR tag, and then look at the contained elements.

```
<tr class='line'>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' class='isHoliday'/> </td>
    <td> <select class='lieuHours'>options...</select> </td>
</tr>
```

and in your script...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
        $('.lines').each(function(i, obj) {
        var lieuHours = $(this).find(".lieuHours").val();
            if ($(this).find(".isHoliday:checked") && lieuHours > 0) {
                alert("cannot process: " + lieuhrs);
                return false;
            }
        }); // missing ); here. <--------------
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't approach the issue properly, the selectors should not be global but specific to the loop you are doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

    $('.lieutimehours').each(function(i, obj) {
        var lieuhrs = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).closest('tr').find('#statholidaycheck').is(":checked") && parseFloat(lieuhrs) > 0) {
            alert('works');
            return false;
        }else{
            alert('fail')
        }
    });

    });
});
```